# Is there a way to do an average over a whole SAS table with SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Say if I had a table

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

And I wanted to find the average so I wanted to sum everything up in the whole table and divide it by the number of data points, so 1+2+3+5+7+9+1+2+3/9

How could I do that in SAS using BASE SAS programming or SAS enterprise guide?

Comment: If you want to treat them as one variable then why do you have the dataset constructed this way?

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough in a data step using the SUM() function and the SUM STATEMENT.

```
data have;
 input var1-var3;
cards;
1 2 3
5 7 9
1 2 3
;

data want;
  set have end=eof;
  sum + sum(of var1-var3);
  n + n(of var1-var3);
  if eof then do;
    mean = sum/n ;
    output;
  end;
  keep sum n mean;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    sum    n      mean

 1      33    9    3.66667
```

If you have an unique ID variable then you can use PROC TRANSPOSE to convert the data to a single variable. THen you can use normal PROCs like MEANS (aka SUMMARY) to calculate the mean.  If you don't have a unique id it is easy to add one.

```
data wide;
  row+1;
  set have;
run;

proc transpose data=wide out=tall;
  by row;
  var var1-var3;
run;

proc means data=tall sum n mean;
  var col1;
run;
```

Result

```
The MEANS Procedure

    Analysis Variable : COL1

         Sum    N            Mean
---------------------------------
  33.0000000    9       3.6666667
---------------------------------
```